# How to set up web app for Clover API / Flask / SSL

Tags: python, flask, ssl, https, clover-payment

I'm trying to create a basic inventory management app for my business. It only needs to run on my machine so I'm running a Flask app on localhost. I've been trying to get the basic code for authorizing with the clover api to work, but i've had so many issues.

```
import flask
import requests
import config
import os
from OpenSSL import SSL
ASSETS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

CLIENT_ID = config.CLIENT_ID
CLIENT_SECRET = config.CLIENT_SECRET
ENV = "https://sandbox.dev.clover.com"

if not CLIENT_ID or not CLIENT_SECRET:
    raise ValueError("Set your CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET in config.py.")

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
context.use_privatekey_file('crt/key.pem')
context.use_certificate_file('crt/certificate.pem')

app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/'

app.config['PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME'] = 'https'


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def landing_page():
    """Depending on whether `code` parameter is present, redirects to
    oauth_callback or to Clover merchant login."""

    # A request from an authorized merchant includes a code in its query string.
    code = flask.request.args.get("code")

    # If the request doesn't include a code, redirect the merchant to Clover's
    # authorize endpoint.
    if not code:
        return flask.redirect("%s/oauth/authorize?client_id=%s" % (ENV, CLIENT_ID))

    # If the request does include a code, redirect to this app's oauth_callback
    # in order to request an access_token.
    else:
        return flask.redirect("/oauth_callback?code=%s" % code)


@app.route("/oauth_callback", methods=["GET"])
def oauth_callback():
    """Uses `code` with CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET to request access_token."""

    code = flask.request.args.get("code")

    # The merchant shouldn't reach this endpoint without a code, but just in case:
    if not code:
        return flask.redirect("/")

    # Use the code with your app ID and app secret to request an access_token.
    request = "%s/oauth/token?client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&code=%s" % (ENV, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, code)

    try:
        response = requests.get(request)
        response.raise_for_status()
        access_token = response.json().get("access_token")
        print("Access token: ", access_token)
        
        if access_token:
            return "Access token: " + access_token
        else:
            return "Could not retrieve access_token."
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print("Request failed:", e)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


################################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True, ssl_context=context)
```

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Feb/2024 19:09:57] code 400, message Bad request version ('**\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03À+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨À\x13À\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x01\x9f\x1a\x1a\x00\x00\x00')
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Feb/2024 19:09:57] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x0c\x01\x00\x02\x08\x03\x03­9Kmñx\x00=;G¢Ë¬\x95\x9c>)\x91ZSqîÝ%µÈ\x86OÞ\x1f>× \x96Büo\x08H4¡6ÆÎÈ´ö¡fÐÔ\x8552È\x00uÚ$ßªàss·\x00 **\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03À+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨À\x13À\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x01\x9f\x1a\x1a\x00\x00\x00" 400 -
```

I generated a self-signed certificate to use HTTPS because I thought that would solve the problem, but I'm still getting errors code 400, bad request version, ssl_protocol_error on Chrome, etc.

I barely changed the below code from the clover site, just added the certificate and a couple debugging things. Anyone have idea what I can try or if there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: It appears the browser ir trying to speak TLS, but the server is not. - verify using curl -vk https://127.0.0.1:5000/ and curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000/ which one gives you more proper logs and responses?

Answer (score 0):

verify it is not speaking plain text -

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

verify it can speak HTTPS

```
curl -vk https://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

If it ***is not*** speaking plain text, find out the versions and details of your TLS configuration

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:5000 -showcerts -debug < /dev/null
```

If I am reading your code right, you’re using SSLv23_METHOD to get an SSLv2-handshake. The browser you are testing with ***may not*** be compatible, hence the 400 bad request. Try TLS 1.2 (or better)

```
context = SSL.Context(SSL.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
```